# Trouble retrieving data from Hikvision fingerprint device using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve data from a Hikvision fingerprint device using Python. Specifically, I am using the Hikvision API, but I am encountering issues with getting the data I need.

I have already checked that the device is properly configured for API access and that I am using the correct API endpoint and syntax. However, when I make a request to the API, I am not getting the expected response.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
import requests

url = "http://192.168.1.64/ISAPI/Intelligent/FingerPrint/UserInfo"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/xml",
    "Authorization": "Basic <base64-encoded-admin-and-password>"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    users = response.json()["UserInfos"]
    print(users)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve user list:", response.status_code)
```

I would appreciate any guidance or advice on how to properly retrieve data from this device using Python and the Hikvision API. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You are specifying `"Content-Type": "application/xml"`, but do you expect Json in return? Is that correct?